# How to add a photograph to a scene and render it realistically?

Tags: objects

I have basic knowledge of Blender, and I use it to render geometric primitives, such as a collection of cubes with different materials.

Now I have a scene with cubes and spheres on a plane (pretty basic) on which I'd like to put a "real object" of which I have a photograph only. This object is for instance a car. I don't have its 3D model, I can only cut it from the photograph.

I would like to incorporate that object in the Blender scene (for example: the car in front of the cube) and render it as realistic as possible. The object is photographed with the right perspective, i.e. from roughly the same angle as it is going to be put in the scene. I do not have big requirements such as reflections.

How can I do it? Is there a general approach?

I am aware of the fact that this is not really the conventional approach. I didn't try pasting the image on the rendered image in Photoshop, but I guess that won't really work.

For further information: I can take new photographs of the objects, and I have control over lighting.

Comment: Have you been able to render your image on a plane yet? http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images

Comment: I have just tried (thanks). However, since I have cut the object from the photogram, my picture is of an irregular shape being transparent in the "empty" parts. Importing it generates a rectangle with black pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I'm going to add this image of the Blender logo:
[image]

Once you get it rendering on a plane, modify the material in the node editor to something like this:

[image]

Comment: Of course, the show of your flat image is going to be ugly since the 3D object isn't actually there. If you want, I can update the answer to show how to create an invisible object which casts a shadow? That way, you could make a crude model of your object to get a makeshift shadow.

Comment: Great, thanks ajwood. Doesn't look too difficult for a beginner.

Comment: Regarding the shadow- I know how to do it.

Comment: Aww.. why the -1 vote?

Comment: Wasn't me :/. I have accepted the answer, but I cannot up-vote it because of no reputation yet.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you had an alpha channel. You probably figured it out already, but you can plug the alpha channel directly into the Fac socket, rather than thresholding the colour channel like in my example.

Comment: Is the transparency handling really _that_ bad (for images that don't have an alpha channel)?